# Inter-StackExchange.com ads

Tags: support

Can something be done on our side to be slightly more selective about what comes up in the inter-stackexchange.com ads we have on the front page? I've just been informed someone has asked whether «"excrement burgers" [are] developed in Japan?» on some site or another...

(And now I cannot submit this because «It does not meet our quality standards.»! The word *excrement* above was in fact the four letter equivalent...)

Comment: It appears to have been asked in the skeptics site. This is a [link to the question](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4739/are-shit-burgers-being-developed-in-japan) in case someone is curious.

Comment: [That question came up on Askubuntu a while ago](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1461/some-se-network-ads-are-offtopic-inappropriate), with regard to a different question from Skeptics.

Answer (score 4):

If by 'we' you mean the users/moderators, in regards to the website itself, then not so much beyond what you have already done (which is posted a discussion on meta and hope that distasteful ads will somehow be filtered upstream).

If by 'we' you mean the users in regards to what they can do on their own personal computers, I'll just note that there are some very nice ad-blocking extensions to each of the various major web browsers.

(As an aside, I'm surprised that the question got posted. If your paraphrase of the question hit the profanity filter, how did the question get posted originally?)

Comment: There is no profanity filter as far as I know, there is only the low quality filter. Probably something else triggered the filter, though the exact nature of this filter is not really known.

Answer (score 4):

You can post a complaint, as you did. The ads are automatically-generated and serve a useful purpose, but if they cause too many problems we'll have to look at finding a better way to choose the topics.